# Basis and weight functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

If we have a weight function $w(x) = e^{-x}$, then how can we find constant and linear polynomials $p0(x), p1(x)$ that are orthogonal on $[0,\infty)$ w.r.t $w(x)$?

And, if we let $f(x) = \cos x$, then what is the best linear approx to $f(x)$ for the given weight?

So, I was looking at the idea of Gram-Schmidt, but it turned out not to be too helpful

Comment: Is there a particular algorithm in mind? Also, it really helps readability to format questions using MahtJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: Gram Schmit, Laguerre Polynomials, something of that sort

Answer (score 2):

- You can choose $p_0(x) = 1$ for example (all values are correct). Then, let's $p_1(x) = ax+b$ and solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} p_0(x)p_1(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} (ax+b) = 0$ to find $a$ and $b$. We obtain $a + b = 0$, so for example $a = b = 1$.
- The best linear approximation $p(x) = cx+d$ is the orthogonal projection of $f$ over the subspace generated by $p_0$ and $p_1$. You can find it by solving $f - p$ orthogonal to this subspace, e.g. $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} (f(x) - p(x))p_0(x) = 0$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} (f(x) - p(x))p_1(x) = 0$. I let you make the rest of the calculation.

Comment: Could you please fill in the computation? It looks like a messy integration by parts

Comment: If you write that $f(x) = Re(e^{ix})$ and use the fact that $Re(\int) = \int Re()$, it becomes easier (you have again to do an integration by parts, but it's not difficult). And don't forget that $\int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-x} = n!$.